# Why is my git push to HostGator shared hosting failing?

Tags: git, shared-hosting, git-push

I'm attempting to deploy my local repo to a remote directory. I've run `git init --bare` in this remote directory, and added the correct ssh path to my local git repo branch (named dev) with `git remote add server ssh://user@domain.com:2222/path/to/repo`.

When I run `git push server dev` I get the following output:

```
Counting objects: 44, done.
Delta compression using up to 8 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (37/37), done.
Writing objects: 100% (44/44), 89.58 KiB, done.
Total 44 (delta 2), reused 27 (delta 2)
error: Could not read 551dd5c5d67e3b2da4074d8f15a59a324a063a03
fatal: Failed to traverse parents of commit 0615b940c3247e3547de1379ab09a4a6bb614252
error: Could not read 551dd5c5d67e3b2da4074d8f15a59a324a063a03
fatal: Failed to traverse parents of commit 0615b940c3247e3547de1379ab09a4a6bb614252
To ssh://user@domain.com:2222/path/to/repo
 ! [remote rejected] dev -> master (missing necessary objects)
error: failed to push some refs to 'ssh://user@domain.com:2222/path/to/repo'
```

I'm not sure what is going on here.

Comment: What does `git fsck` say about your local repository?

Comment: Thanks, I'm still learning the basics of git. I had dangling commits and I believe that was causing the problem. This is a fresh repo for me so I simply deleted it and created a new repo and dev branch from scratch.

Comment: Dangling commits wouldn't be a problem, they are only commits that are not referenced -- junk that will be cleaned up later.  What would be concerning is if one of your commits referenced a parent commit that doesn't exist.

Comment: I'm not sure how that would occur. However I was playing around with this repo learning the basics of git so it's definitely possible that I deleted a parent commit or something of that nature.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned in "[git repository failed to traverse parent error](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9539126/6309)", this can also be caused by a shallow clone.

In your case though (testing repo), restarting from scratch is the easiest.

In general, you have interesting advices in [this thread](http://git.661346.n2.nabble.com/fetch-and-bundle-don-t-work-in-semi-broken-repo-td5651528.html):

> 1. Use "`git rev-list --objects`" to find out what `40aaeb204dc` was.
>
> And if that doesn't work:
>
> 2. Run "`git fsck --full`", with packs intact.  This will take a while.
>   The result would include a list of missing objects (like `40aaeb204dc`), and, most importantly, their type.
>
> Following [howto/recover-corrupted-blob-object.txt](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/Documentation/howto/recover-corrupted-blob-object.txt) would be useful for identifying a corrupt loose object.