# Issue on pushing Github code to Bitbucket

Tags: github, bitbucket

When I am trying to push my existing repository from github to bitbucket, I get this:-

```
# git push
Counting objects: 1025, done.
Delta compression using up to 2 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (661/661), done.
Writing objects: 100% (1025/1025), 2.02 MiB, done.
Total 1025 (delta 302), reused 909 (delta 227)
error: Could not read d97e763d22304ebfa5a1fb7ba9468cb36d4eff49
fatal: Failed to traverse parents of commit 57211de122c9b449c2b4bb0d37ac6a73545a9c68
error: Could not read d97e763d22304ebfa5a1fb7ba9468cb36d4eff49
fatal: Failed to traverse parents of commit 57211de122c9b449c2b4bb0d37ac6a73545a9c68
To ssh://git@bitbucket.org/techvineet/task-manager.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (missing necessary objects)
error: failed to push some refs to 'ssh://git@bitbucket.org/techvineet/test-site.git'
```

What I m doing wrong?

Comment: While using GIT the first thing you should do is to check your local repository status, try to do `git status` and let us know whats happening there!

Comment: Seems to be a similar problem as this post:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13301748/why-is-my-git-push-to-hostgator-shared-hosting-failing

Comment: @Rishi # On branch master
# Untracked files:
#   (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)
#
# .project
nothing added to commit but untracked files present (use "git add" to track)

Answer (score 1):

You can do the following things:

- Go to your local GIT repository similar to this `C:\xampp\htdocs\<project>\.git` where `.git` is a hidden folder.
- Open the `config` file available there, it must contains the code similar to this

```
    [core]
        repositoryformatversion = 0
        filemode = false
        bare = false
        logallrefupdates = true
        symlinks = false
        ignorecase = true
        hideDotFiles = dotGitOnly``
    [remote "origin"]
        url = ssh://git@bitbucket.org/techvineet/test-site.git
        fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
    [branch "master"]
        remote = origin
        merge = refs/heads/master
```

- Replace the `ssh://git@bitbucket.org/techvineet/test-site.git` with `https://<your_username>@bitbucket.org/techvineet/test-site.git`
- Here you can also permanently save your password, which can save your time while using GIT by appending your password after a colon, `https://techvineet:techvineet123@bitbucket.org/techvineet/test-site.git` where **techvineet** should be your username and **techvineet123** should be the password for the same.
- Save the file and close your current GIT session.
- Open a new session and check one again `git status` if any untracked files are remaining to add use `git add *` to add then use `git commit -a -m 'Your Message'` to commit your files, remember never push before pulling the stuffs. There you can use `git pull` and then use `git push`
- This should be done. Please check and let me know.

Cheers!